# Javascript bind() vs createDelegate()

Tags: javascript, extjs

Imagine I want to pass a member function as a callback.

What should I use to pass a context - bind() or createDelegate()?

I mean, this:

```
someObj.on('someEvent', this.someMethod.createDelegate(this));
```

Or this:

```
someObj.on('someEvent', this.someMethod.bind(this));
```

Comment: What framework are you working with? Do you mean in jQuery?

Comment: `createDelegate` is not a native JavaScript method.

Comment: Depends on what `createDelegate` does.

Comment: If you or any visitor are interested in Function.createDelagate from AJAX.NET, refer to this this verbose post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881544/asp-net-ajax-function-createdelegate-vs-function-createcallback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bind` function is a recent addition to ECMA-262(Javascript), 5th edition;

The `createDelegate` is not a native JavaScript method in any edition.

So better to use `bind`. And use [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility) for browser where it not implemented.

P.S. If you use any popular framework, probably it has such methods. For example jQuery has `$.proxy` static method that do the same.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using an old version of ExtJS (3.4.0 for example), there is little difference in what `bind` and `createDelegate` do. The big difference comes from the fact that `bind` is not available for older browsers.

One thing to note is that `createDelegate` is not available in newer versions of ExtJS, as the framework has moved away from the idea of changing native object prototypes. It has been replaced by `Ext.Function.bind`.

*) There is some difference between the native `Function.prototype.bind` and `Ext.Function.bind`, in how the arguments bound to the function are treated. It doesn't look like it affects your code, though. Read the documentation to see the exact difference.

MDN link for `Function.prototype.bind`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

ExtJS 3.4.0 link for `Function.prototype.createDelegate` (added by ExtJS)

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/source/Ext.html#Function-method-createDelegate

ExtJS 4.0.7 link for `Ext.Function.bind`

http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/source/Function2.html#Ext-Function-method-bind

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about jQuery, look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) (second parameter `eventData`)

```
someObj.on('someEvent', {me: this}, this.someMethod);
```

someObj:

```
{

    someMethod: function(eventData){
      var me = eventData.me;
    }

}
```